# How to access mapState property inside the method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I access the `count` property inside the `method` when I use vuex? Please see my code below.

**Code screenshot**:
[image]

**Error**

> [Vue warn]: Computed property "count" was assigned to but it has no setter.

Comment: You can access it the way you do. You shouldn't modify it. This is what actions and mutations are for.

Comment: @EstusFlask So this means, I just have to create actions/mutations to increment the value of the `count` and then call it inside that method?

Comment: Yes, that's how Vuex is supposed to be used.

Comment: @EstusFlask Alright, got the idea. Just new here in vuex :)

Answer (score 1):

The `mapState` you wrote is inside a `computed` block. By default `computed` values are read-only, but you can make them read/write by giving them a setter *(ie a function to call when modifying the computed value)*:

```js
computed: {

  count: {
    get() { return this.$store.state.count; },
    set(newValue) {
      // This will most likely throw a warning, as it is bad practise.
      this.$store.state.count = newValue;
    }
  }

}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Answer (score 1):

You can access computed properties just like you access your data properties in a component. But since you are mapping the state in this case. You should not increment or alter its value directly inside the component. Instead, you should dispatch an action with the updated/incremented value and use mutation to mutate the value of the count property in the state object.
More detail https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#commit-with-payload